# How to default to not sending email when a user is added to a Group

Tags: 2013, user-accounts, notifications

When I add a user to a group in SharePoint Foundation 2013 I have to click the advanced option and untick the send notification email option.

How do I make the default 'No'

The reason I want to do this is that it's sending a local intranet link and not the extranet link.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you can do it for particular web, site collection or web application because it's hard coded in "\LAYOUTS\AclInv.aspx" page.

So if you want to change it, then you need to update that file.(First take back of that aspx page for being in safe line. Open that file in notepad and find following tag.

```
             <asp:CheckBox
                runat="server"
                id="chkSendEmailv15"
                Checked="true"
                class = "ms-aclinv-checkbox"
                OnClick="UpdateSendEmailMessage()"/>
```

Update that "Checked" property to "false"

But note that if you update this then it will apply to whole SharePoint environment.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: SharePoint truly is the worst. How does this affect any future updates?